# Trouble using .replace() in function

Tags: python

I'm coding a function in Python for an assignment that takes an input string and removes/replaces certain substrings. I'm having success removing certain words from the string, but having trouble replacing certain strings. Please be gentle, as I'm a novice :)

Any recommendations on how to improve? Also, I can't use `import` for this question.

```py
def cleaning_noise(sentence):
    
    words = sentence.split()
    count = 1
    for word in words:
        
        if "http" in word:
            
            words.remove(word)
            continue
            
        if word == "\n":
            
            words.remove(word)
            continue
        
        if "#" in word:
            
            words.remove(word)
            continue      
        
        if "\n" in word:
            
            word = word.replace("\n", " ")
         
        if "&amp" in word:
            
            word = word.replace("&amp", "&")
            
        if count % 2 != 0:
            
            if "@" in word:
                
                word = words.remove(word)
                count += 1

    text = " ".join(words)
                
    return text
```

Comment: Could you be more specific as to which replace fails? Could you post the expected vs. actual output?

Comment: which strings are you having troubles with?

Comment: I think you probably want to avoid modifying `words` while you are explicitly iterating over its elements. Maybe try `i = 0`, `while i < len(words)`, indented `word = words[i]`, and then increment `i` every time you don't remove a word (but don't increment `i` if you do remove a word, otherwise you will skip over the next word)

Comment: You shouldn't be mutating the list over which you're iterating.

Comment: Also, instead of doing `if "\n" in word: word = word.replace("\n", " ")`, you can just do `word = word.replace("\n", " ")` (IE you don't need to check if `"\n"` is in `word` or not, if it's not there then nothing will happen

Comment: Also think about this: is there *ever* a case you could have `"\n"` in a word in that code?

Comment: `if count % 2 != 0:` will never be `True` as it's `False` for `count=1`, so `count` will never get incremented.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you shouldn't try to remove items from a container that you are iterating over.

In your case I would create a new container and add words that are allowed to that and use the `.join()` on that to get the string to return:

```py
def cleaning_noise(sentence):
    
    words = sentence.split()
    count = 1
    allowed = []
    for word in words:
        if "http" in word:
            continue
        if "#" in word:
            continue      
        
        if "&amp" in word:
            word = word.replace("&amp", "&")
            
        if count % 2 != 0:
            if "@" in word:
                count += 1
                continue

        allowed.append(word)

    return " ".join(allowed)
```

Comment: Can `"\n" in word` ever be true here? Is there a reason why you still kept a call to `remove` in there?

Comment: Ok, I'll remove the `"\n"` parts since `.split()` removes those along with spaces. The `remove` I'll have a think about.

Comment: I changed the last `remove` to `continue` since that seems to be the intention.

Comment: Does this even work? With ```'http \n # &amp @'``` I get ```TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found```

Comment: Yes, it does. With your suggested test case I get just `"&"` as the return. Please check which version you are using as I have updated it a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more succinct approach which eliminates many of the if statements by placing all the words to be removed in a set and all the words having a single replacement into a dictionary structure.

```
def cleaning_noise(sentence: str) -> str:
    rem_words = {'http', '\n', '#'}
    rep_words = {'\n': '', '&amp': '&'}
    words = sentence.split()
    count = 1
    rslt = []
    for word in words:
        print('search', word, count)
        if word not in rem_words:
            if word in rep_words.keys():
                for ky, val in rep_words.items():
                    print(ky, word)
                    if ky in word:
                        print(word, ky)
                        rslt.append(word.replace(ky, val))
            elif count % 2 != 0 and '@' in word:
                count +=1
                print('count', count)
            else:
                rslt.append(word)
    return ' '.join(rslt)
```